# NameError using Tkinter get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, callback, widget

I am creating a drop-down menu using tkinter. It has a submenu "File" and a command "Open" with an entry to allow the user to type the path of the file they want to open and click a button to open it. Currently I'm trying to use get() to retrieve the entry text when the button is clicked, as shown in my code below:

```
# Assign 5
from tkinter import *

def getFile():
'Displays the text in the entry'
print(E1.get())

def openFile():
'Creates enty widget that allows user file path and open it'
win = Tk()
#add label 
L1 = Label(win, text="File Name")
#display label
L1.pack()
#add entry widget
E1 = Entry(win, bd = 5)
#display entry
E1.pack(fill=X)
#create buttons 
b1 = Button(win, text="Open", width=10, command = getFile)
b2 = Button(win, text = "Cancel", width=10, command=win.quit)
#display the buttons
b1.pack(side = LEFT)
b2.pack(side = LEFT)

# create a blank window 
root = Tk()
root.title("Emmett's awesome window!")

#create a top level menu
menubar = Menu(root)  
# add drop down "File" menu with command "Open" to the menubar
fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = openFile)    

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/emmettgreenberg/Documents/2016/CS521/assign5/assign5_2.py", line  6, in getFile
print(E1.get())
NameError: name 'E1' is not defined
```

From what I understand, I do not need to pass *E1* as an argument when I call *getFile* . How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since `E1` is a local variable inside `openFile()` and so it cannot be accessed inside `getFile()`.  Either you make `E1` global or pass the content of `E1` via `getFile()`:

```
def getFile(filename):
    print(filename)

def openFile():
    ...
    b1 = Button(win, text="Open", width=10, command=lambda: getFile(E1.get()))
    ...
```

Or you can define global `StringVar` to hold the filename and associate it with `E1`:

```
def getFile():
    print(filename.get())

def openFile():
    ...
    E1 = entry(win, bd=5, textvariable=filename)
    ...

root = Tk()
filename = StringVar()
```

BTW, better change `win = Tk()` to `win = Toplevel()` inside `openFile()`.

Comment: Thanks, I used lambda to pass the filename and it works but I don't understand, why is lambda needed? Also, why use **Toplevel()** instead of **Tk()**?

Comment: @EmmettGreenberg In general, an tkinter app should have exactly 1 Tk master application widget.  Having more than one can lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: lambda is used in order to pass any resources defined within the scope of `openFile()` function to `getFile()` function.  Using `Tk()` will initialize another instance of `root` window which is independent to the first created `root` window, but `Toplevel()` will be within the hierarchy of the first `root` window.  Seems both can do the same effect, but the meanings behind are different.